# Send faster POST request from chrome (extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, google-chrome, post

I am still kind of new to JS and would need some advice.

I have a chrome extension that successfully sends a POST request to a website and logs the response to the console. This works perfectly fine. I am using jQuery's "AJAX" for this.

The problem I am having is, that there are at least 5 to 10 seconds from sending the actual request until receiving the response. I am looking for a way to speed this up as much as possible.

I am not only looking for coding advice, but also for an easy explanation if the time that a request takes, only relies on the server or if there are other things I can do from my end.

Here is my function to send the request:

```
function sendRequest(itemID, token) {
    beep.play();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://website.com/url.json',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            "items": itemID,
            "token": token
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Response: ' + data);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Error:' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Pretty basic actually. "Token" is a string with 22 characters, "itemID" is also a string, but with 30-40 characters. Both values are required - so I am not sending any unnecessary data that would slow down the process.

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: navigate to `https://website.com/url.json` within chrome (i.e. put that URL into the omnibox) and see how long the page takes to load.

Comment: @TylerSebastian It is fully loaded after ~100ms but shows a message (in the website's layout), that there is "nothing to do here". Probably because it's only for sending requests to. ;)

Comment: ah, whoops, I just noticed that it's a POST request. Try something like Postman or Insomnia and try again (ensure that it's a POST request)

Comment: There's nothing really wrong with your code, I'd be doing as @TylerSebastian suggested and testing your endpoint using something like Postman. If you have control over the endpoint I'd also be debugging that code to see where the delays are occurring - is that code calling out to 3rd party services, is it doing any database reads, etc.

Comment: @Chris No control over the endpoint in this case. It is probably reading out a rather small database for the ItemID I requested and then hands over a command to (most likely) a nodeJS script that interacts with a 3rd party network (Steam). At this point it should give me the response if it succeeded or failed and the Steam network will do some actions from their side. I can't really try with postman because there is a 2FA login on the website, but chrome dev tools showed, that the request (like 0.8ms) is followed by 9 sec "time to first byte". Nothing I can do, I guess. Right?

Comment: @ThomasWeiss Yeah unfortunately it doesn't sound like there's anything you can do then.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot then! :) @Chris

Answer (score 1):

To finish this up: Since the request is causing actions with a 3rd party network and the ttfb (time to first byte) is what causes the delay, there is nothing I can do except hope for the website to improve their backend! Thanks to Chris and Tyler!